# Namespace exists but not found and absent in Object Browser

Tags: reference, namespaces, umbraco, umbraco7

I am trying to use Archetype model namespace (Archetype.Models) in my code behind. The ddl exists in bin and my views see the namespace.

```
using Archetype.Models;
```

However when I want to use it in a controller it gives an error saying the namespace couldn't be found.

I can see it is not listed in my project Object Browser - may this be related? If so how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I checked references and actually had to add the reference to dll
My controller then started to see the archetype model